# How do I move a line in a file to the top from the command line?

Tags: unix, vim, sed

I would like to move a path in a file to the top of the file. Each path is listed 1 per line. How do I move `/someplace/2nd/` to the top using only the command line?

```
/someplace/1st/
/someplace/2nd/
/someplace/3rd/
```

So I end up with

```
/someplace/2st/
/someplace/1nd/
/someplace/3rd/
```

Comment: From the command line, it is always easier to generate a new file given an input file than to edit a file in place (change its contents). Is that good enough for you? After you've generated the new file you can always move it back to the original filename (thus squashing the original file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you used the `vim` tag I'll assume first that you meant Vim's command line. If that's the case, then this command will do it.

```
:g/^\/someplace\/2nd\/$/m0
```

where that last character is a zero. See

```
:help :g
:help :m
```

In the event that you meant the shell command line, you can use `vim` to edit your file using this command.

```
vim -c 'g/^\/someplace\/2nd\/$m0' -cwq yourfile
```

See

```
:help -c
:help :wq
```

Comment: `:/^\/someplace\/2nd\/$/m0`, without using `:g`, should be enough maybe with a shorter pattern.

Comment: I was looking for the command line version. I used the pattern as romainl suggested. Works great. Going to update my script to use the vim command. Thank you both.

Answer (score 4):

The traditional way to edit files in place non-interactively is by using `ed`:

```
(echo '/^\/someplace\/2nd\/$/m0'; echo w; echo q ) | ed $file
```

That sends 3 commands to the `ed` text editor running on the file `$file`:

- `/regular_expression/m0`: search for a line matching `regular_expression` and move it to position 0
- `w`: write the file
- `q`: quit

Answer (score 2):

```
{
  sed -n '/^\/someplace\/2nd\//{p;q}' file
  sed    '/^\/someplace\/2nd\//d' file
} > temp && mv temp file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '1,\|/someplace/2nd/|{1{h;d};//!{H;d};G}' file
```